# Minus SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a quick sql query for an 'invite your friends to this group' script.

I have 2 tables: users and group_members. I'm trying to do a query that selects all of my friends--represented by the first select--and subtract all of my friends from the users that are already represented and part of the group--represented by the second select.

I keep getting syntax error and not sure why. When I run each select query by itself, it properly shows me all of my friends uid's (using the first query) as well as all of the uids of the group members (using the second query)

```
(SELECT a.uid, a.name_f, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, a.location FROM users a, friends b WHERE a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = $VAR 
MINUS 
SELECT a.uid, a.name_f, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, a.location FROM users a, group_members m WHERE m.teamid = 95 and a.uid = m.userid)
```

Comment: So what's the syntax error you get?

Comment: Here it is: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MINUS SELECT a.uid, a.name_f, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, a.location FROM users a' at line 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not support `MINUS`.  You can usually recreate it through the use of a `NOT IN` subquery.  This may do the job:

```
SELECT
  a.uid,
  a.name_f,
  a.name_l,
  a.profile_pic, 
  a.location 
FROM users a, friends b 
WHERE a.uid = b.friend_two AND b.friend_one = $VAR
  AND a.uid NOT IN (
    SELECT subuser.uid FROM users subuser, group_members m WHERE m.teamid = 95 AND subuser.uid = m.uid
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sub-query for this:

```
SELECT a.uid, a.name_f, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, a.location
FROM users a, friends b 
WHERE a.uid = b.friend_two 
  AND b.friend_one = $VAR
  AND a.uid NOT IN ( 
                   SELECT a.uid FROM users a, group_members m  
                   WHERE m.teamid=95 AND a.uid=m.userid)
```

See how your second query is part of the `AND a.uid NOT IN (second_query)`?

In fact, I think you can even do this without a sub-query:

```
SELECT a.uid, a.name_f, a.name_l, a.profile_pic, a.location
FROM users a
JOIN friends b ON a.uid = b.friend_two
JOIN group_members m ON a.uid=m.userid
WHERE b.friend_one = $VAR
  AND m.teamid != 95
```

This just joins all the tables together, selects the ones with the appropriate `b.friend_one`, and filters out the ones already in the `m.teamid`.

Comment: I'm going to have to try this out too. Thanks a lot.